# Why ComboBox is not working after applying Resize and Move functionality to PopUpDiv

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a normal `Div` with title-header ['Resize and Move Me! , Combobox'] and body part as mention below in link.
When I applied move and resize functionality using javascript, ComboBox on header part is not working. It would not drop list. If I put Combobox outside of that `DIVs` then its working properly,But inside it would not. See example,

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/beingcoders/5kd5qftw/3/)

I have few questions

1. Can anyone tell me the reason that why its not working?
2. What should be the solution to make it work properly.

Comment: it is not working because you copied from somewhere .

Comment: What is a *normal* PopUpDiv?

Comment: @Mahi Yes I applied this js from codepen to my Div and I am stuck with combobox.

Comment: @ScottMarcus let say normal DIV

Comment: This Helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, in one the mouse click events, you are trying to block the default behavior of the select box.

```
function onMouseDown(e) {
   onDown(e);
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Here e.preventDefault, is blocking the select box from showing the options when you click the mouse.

Please comment/delete it out to get the normal behavior of the select box.